# How to show 1 element of array dynamically with php?

Tags: php, arrays

in "file.txt" i have some numbers like 1234,123456,12345678 etc.
so i was wondering how i can get dynamically just one element, for example echo just 12345,then echo 123456, but one by one ???when user comes i want to show him one element,and then next time i want to show another element on the page, it would be good also if i could erase elements that i have echo...When i manually enter position it works... Please help...

I have a following code:

```
function test($n){
  $file=file_get_contents("file.txt");
  $array = explode(",", $file);
  return print_r($array[$n]);
};
```

Comment: Do you want to show a random entry or the next entry based on visit history?

Comment: just save in your session what you still have to show and then pop each time what you want to show now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is usually a terrible way of doing this.
It's much better to use a database, for example.

But you could do the following:

```
<?php

function getRandomNumber() {
  // retrieve and parse the numbers
  $numbers = file_get_contents('file.txt');
  $numbers = explode(',' $numbers);

  // select a random index
  $randomIndex = array_rand($numbers);

  // get the chosen number
  $randomNumber = $numbers[$randomIndex];

  // remove it from array
  unset($numbers[$randomIndex]);

  // save updated file
  file_put_contents('file.txt', implode(',', $numbers));

  return $randomNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution will need deleting the number on your filesystem or marking it as already showed either on the filesystem or on the database, after the number gets echoed.

Shuffling the numbers or generating a random index will never quite be full proof since the same number could be shown again.